Feeding a subset of an array to a combobox in a form
I have an Excel form with comboboxes.
Each combobox is set up as an array in the following way
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Creates entries for all comboboxes in the Add/Remove Equipment Form
InstType = Array("USBL System", "GNSS System", "Heading System")
InstManf = Array("Sonardyne", "Kongsberg", "Exail", "Fugro", "CNav", "Veripos", "Teledyne")
InstGen = Array("Unknown", "1st Gen", "2nd Gen", "3rd Gen", "4th Gen", "5th Gen", "6th Gen")
AccUnit = Array("% slant range", "degrees", "metres", "deg secant lat.")
ErrLevel = Array("1DRMS", "2DRMS", "1" & ChrW(963), "2" & ChrW(963), "R95")
ErrType = Array("Random", "Systematic")

'Adds entire array to particular comboboxes in the Add/Remove Equipment Form
CbxInstType.List = InstType
CbxInstGen.List = InstGen
CbxErrLevel.List = ErrLevel
CbxErrType.List = ErrType

InstManfSubset = InstManf(3)
CbxInstManf.List = InstManfSubset

End Sub

On
InstManfSubset = InstManf(3)

I get

Run-time error 381: Could not set the list property. Invalid property array index"

I want a subset of the InstManf array to fill the CbxInstManf combobox.
My subset is just one value. For troubleshooting I tried to send one value to my CbxInstManf combobox.
It seems supplying a combobox with an array is not a problem. I can for example do the following.
CbxErrLevel.List = Array("1DRMS", "2DRMS", "1" & ChrW(963), "2" & ChrW(963), "R95")

It's when I try to feed a portion of a particular array to the combobox that I get the error.
Is the list function not geared to take a subset of an array?
I tried declaring both InstManf and InstManfSubset as an array but it doesn't make any difference. I get the same error.

A single item from an array is not an array, so maybe try InstManfSubset = Array(InstManf(3)) with InstManfSubset declared as Variant

CbxInstManf.AddItem InstManfSubset!?

Thanks @TimWilliams  this did the trick!

Thanks for your help too @VBasic2008!
